# Saving SQL Server backup file in multiple parts

Tags: sql-server, backup

I am taking daily backups of a SQL Server database. Right now the `.bak` file is about 2GB and it is growing day by day. There is a scheduled job is running which moves this `.bak` file from one location to another.

Is there a way to save the `.bak` file in chunks - like `part1.bak`, `part2.bak` etc..

so it will be much easier to move small data and merge at destination?

Comment: Alternative: if you're using SQL Server 2008+ Enterprise Edition, look into [backup compression](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb964719(v=sql.100).aspx). Otherwise, if you "just" want smaller dumps for transferring them from location A to B, and otherwise have enough disk space, just manually ZIP them. There is usually quite some space to gain here.

Comment: Actually I am trying to automate process, and not go through manual process. Because I know that this .bak file will be about 50+ GB in near feature and moving from source to destination will be big hassle.

Would it be nice idea to write C# application which will go and .zip  this .bak file and split them into pieces? like 10MB per part. maybe.

Comment: My "alternative" could easily be automated as well; "manually ZIP" didn't mean that you do that manually every time, but rather that you use a tool like `7za.exe`, possibly scripted, instead of a builtin mechanism of SQL Server. I'm not aware of a built-in way to write a backup in parts. And the [BACKUP](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186865.aspx) T-SQL command doesn't seem to have an option. You could try backing up individual filegroups, but I'm not sure if there are any caveats to that.

Comment: Also, you could use a tool like the [`split`](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/aix/v7r1/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.aix.cmds%2Fdoc%2Faixcmds5%2Fsplit.htm) to "manually" split a larger file into chunks of smaller sizes. While it is UNIX utility it will surely be available in one or more UNIX-Tools collections for windows (like Cygwin), or there may even by a true Windows port or a comparable tool.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Normal backup

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SET STATISTICS TIME ON

BACKUP DATABASE DBNAME
TO DISK = 'D:\DBNAME.bak'

SET STATISTICS IO OFF

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

to split the size into 3 use the following code, it will split the size of 3 gb into 1 GB each file
you can add more files or less depending on the size you want

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON

SET STATISTICS TIME ON


BACKUP DATABASE DBNAME TO

DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\DBNAME _Split1.bak'

,DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\DBNAME _Split2.bak'

,DISK = 'D:\DBBackups\ReportServer\DBNAME _Split3.bak'


SET STATISTICS IO OFF

SET STATISTICS TIME OFF
```

for more details

http://beyondrelational.com/modules/2/blogs/88/posts/10153/sql-server-split-database-full-backup-to-multiple-files.aspx

Comment: so easy and works like a charm, even so many years later! thanks for this gem

Answer (score 0):

May be you'd like to use differential backup. It backups only data changed from the last backup, so you'll copy only the small amount of data.